# How to capture screen movies records on the Linux framebuffer

Tags: linux, screen, records, framebuffer, movies

How can the linux frame buffer be captured to obtain screen movies?

i have understanded how to get the framebuffer and convert to a image, but i dont know how to record them to a movies.

can someone tell me some way to convert the framebuffer into a movies? or give me some examples to show.c or java is both ok.